# how to distinguish a free user from a paid one - freemium app in chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, chrome-web-store

those are the actions I've done so far:
i've got myself a new project in developers console here:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/

and enable those api's:
* Chrome Web Store API

- Google+ API
- BigQuery API
- Debuglet Controller API
- Google Cloud SQL
- Google Cloud Storage
- Google Cloud Storage JSON API

my guess is I don't really need all of them . . .

in "credentials" under APIs and auth I have "Client ID for Chrome application".

I took the "client ID" and planted it in my manifest.json file like this:

```
"oauth2": {
        "client_id": "blablablabla.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes": [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
        ]
    }
```

also those are my chrome extension permissions in the manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "tabs",
        "cookies",
        "management",
        "notifications",
        "contextMenus",
        "management",
        "storage",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "identity"
    ],
```

i've got myself a new project in developers console here:
https://code.google.com/apis/console
don't know if I needed to . . .

when i'm trying to do this request:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
            var CWS_LICENSE_API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/userlicenses/';
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('GET', CWS_LICENSE_API_URL + chrome.runtime.id);
            req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (req.readyState == 4) {
                var license = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                if (license.accessLevel == "FULL") {
                    // paid
                }
                else {
                    // free
                }
              }
            }
            req.send();
        });
```

i'm getting a 403 (Forbidden) error - "Insufficient Permission".

Just to be clear the getAuthToken request doe's provide me with the token.

all I want is to distinguish a free user from a paid one. way is that so hard :(

Answer (score 1):

Not that this answer is timely but you need to include an additional scope that allows you to get the api result.

The scope required for that request is: 
`"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"`

You can read more on how to authorize and use that api call at: 
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/userLicenses/getUserLicense